# How to normalize columns with one-hot encoding efficiently in pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, one-hot-encoding

A column of an example dataframe is shown:

```
Fruit   FruitA  FruitB
Apple   Banana  Mango
Banana  Apple   Apple
Mango   Apple   Banana
Banana  Mango   Banana
Mango   Banana  Apple
Apple   Mango   Mango
```

I want to introduce new columns in the dataframe `Fruit-Apple`, `Fruit-Mango`, `Fruit-Banana` with one-hot encoding in the rows they are respectively present. So, the desired output is:

```
Fruit   FruitA  FruitB  Fruit-Apple Fruit-Banana    Fruit-Mango
Apple   Banana  Mango   1           1           1
Banana  Apple   Apple   1           1           0
Mango   Apple   Banana  1           1           1
Banana  Mango   Banana  0           1           1
Mango   Banana  Apple   1           1           1
Apple   Mango   Mango   1           0           1
```

My code to do this is:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
        if (data['Fruits'][i] == 'Apple' or data['FruitsA'][i] == 'Apple' or data['FruitsB'][i] == 'Apple'):
            data['Fruits-Apple'][i]=1
            data['Fruits-Banana'][i]=0
            data['Fruits-Mango'][i]=0
        elif (data['Fruits'][i] == 'Banana' or data['FruitsA'][i] == 'Banana' or data['FruitsB'][i] == 'Banana'):
            data['Fruits-Apple'][i]=0
            data['Fruits-Banana'][i]=1
            data['Fruits-Mango'][i]=0
        elif (data['Fruits'][i] == 'Mango' or data['FruitsA'][i] == 'Mango' or data['FruitsB'][i] == 'Mango'):
            data['Fruits-Apple'][i]=0
            data['Fruits-Banana'][i]=0
            data['Fruits-Mango'][i]=1
```

But I notice that the time taken for running this code increases dramatically if there are a lot of types of 'fruits'. In my actual data, there are only 1074 rows, and the column I'm trying to "normalize" with one-hot encoding has 18 different values. So, there are 18 `if` conditions inside the for loop, and the code hasn't finished running for 15 mins now. That's absurd (It would be great to know why its taking so long - in another column that contained only 6 different types of values, the code took much less time to execute, about 3 mins).

So, what's the best (vectorized) way to achieve this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Fruit']).add_prefix('Fruit-'))
print (df)
    Fruit  Fruit-Apple  Fruit-Banana  Fruit-Mango
0   Apple            1             0            0
1  Banana            0             1            0
2   Mango            0             0            1
3  Banana            0             1            0
4   Mango            0             0            1
5   Apple            1             0            0
```

EDIT: If input are multiple columns use `get_dummies` with `max` by columns:

```
df = (df.join(pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
               .max(level=0, axis=1)
               .add_prefix('Fruit-')))
print (df)
    Fruit  FruitA  FruitB  Fruit-Apple  Fruit-Banana  Fruit-Mango
0   Apple  Banana   Mango            1             1            1
1  Banana   Apple   Apple            1             1            0
2   Mango   Apple  Banana            1             1            1
3  Banana   Mango  Banana            0             1            1
4   Mango  Banana   Apple            1             1            1
5   Apple   Mango   Mango            1             0            1
```

For better performance use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) with DataFrame converted to `list`s:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.values.tolist()),
                  columns=mlb.classes_, 
                  index=df.index).add_prefix('Fruit-'))
print (df)
    Fruit  FruitA  FruitB  Fruit-Apple  Fruit-Banana  Fruit-Mango
0   Apple  Banana   Mango            1             1            1
1  Banana   Apple   Apple            1             1            0
2   Mango   Apple  Banana            1             1            1
3  Banana   Mango  Banana            0             1            1
4   Mango  Banana   Apple            1             1            1
5   Apple   Mango   Mango            1             0            1
```

Comment: I have edited the dataframe and the desired output in the question.

Comment: But what if there are more columns in the dataframe, like `VegetableA`, `vegetableB`, etc? How do I specify the columns (like, `Fruit`, `FruitA` and `FruitB` in the example in the question) which are needed to be one-hot encoded?

Comment: @Kristada673 - I think best is use `df.filter(like='Fruit')`

Comment: For my dataframe, the `get_dummies` with `max` solution produces a one-hot encoding for each of the columns separately, which is not what I want. And the sklearn solution produces the following error: `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`.

Comment: @Kristada673 - Waht about `df.filter(like='Fruit').astype(str).values.tolist()` for `MultiLabelBinarizer` solution?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but after restarting the jupyter notebook kernel, the `get_dummies` with `max` solution now works!

Comment: @Kristada673 - Super, glad can help!